# Algorithm: Coin Change - Counting the number of ways one can give change

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

I am trying to understand the DP behind the coin change problem, where one is supposed to count the number of ways you can give change for a denomination given a set of coins. Each coin is present infinite number of times.

The algorithm is taken from [this](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dynamic-programming-set-7-coin-change/) geeks4geeks page. The algorithms is the following (where N stands for denomination and dp is an array of size N+1):

```
dp[0] = 1
for each coin c:
    for i from c to N:
        if i >=  c:
            dp[i] += dp[i-c]
```

I am not able to understand how is the DP working here and what are the subproblems.

Edit: I checked other related questions but none mentions the algorithm stated above. A 2-D DP solution is discussed in previous questions.

Comment: That algorithm is a simplification of the previous 2D DP algorithm given in that link. If you look at the way you reference back to other indices in the previous algorithm, it should be easy to see that it can be simplified in this way. This is not so much about thinking in terms of subproblems as it is thinking in terms of simplification.

Comment: Well, I am not able to understand the simplification and that is why I have asked for help. Thanks!

Comment: Basically, `table[:]` in the second one is `table[:][j]` in the first one. The rest is the same. They switched around the indices, which might make things confusing. It's not uncommon in DP to notice that you only look back a single row and thus you don't need to store the entire matrix, sometimes you store the current and last row separately, but here you can just overwrite as you go.

Answer (score 1):

You can consider this approach as solving C subproblems where C is the number of coins.

Subproblem c consists of "Which values can be made from coins up to and including coin c, but not including any coins of greater value."

The base subproblem then becomes "Which values can be made from no coins", to which the answer is just the value 0.

Then to work out each additional subproblem we can iterate through the array marking values as possible if they consist of some value made from previous coin values plus some number of coins of the current value.

As we are updating the DP array in-place, it turns out that we only have to consider adding one coin of the current value for each location in the array.